# Why does the remove_exception function give a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

Here the code, I have a linked list of words, and a linked list of exception words. I wish to delete the exception words from the linked list of words. But it gives me a segmentation fault for a few of my test cases and I can't seem to understand why.

Here is my code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "emalloc.h"
#include "listy.h"
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 100
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 40
#define MAX_WORDS_PER_LINE

typedef struct Lines_and_Words Lines_and_Words;
struct Lines_and_Words{
    char array_lines[MAX_LINE_LEN];
};

struct Ntab{
    Lines_and_Words *lines;
    int max_elements;
    int index;
};

enum{
    NINIT = 8,
    NGROW = 2
};

void command_line_input(int argc, char *argv[], char **input_file, char **exp_filename);
void read_file_in_array(char *filename, struct Ntab *ntab);
int add_line(char *line, struct Ntab *ntab);
void store_words(struct Ntab *ntab, node_t **words, int *word_counter);
void remove_exceptions(node_t **words, node_t **exp_words, int *word_counter);
node_t *remove_word(node_t *words, char *text);
void sort(node_t **words, int word_counter);
int compare(const void *a, const void *b);
void remove_duplicates(node_t **words, int *word_counter);
void print_output(node_t **words, struct Ntab *ntab_lines, int word_counter);
int longest_word(node_t **words);
int count_words_in_line(char word[MAX_WORD_LEN], char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN]);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *filename = NULL;
    struct Ntab ntab_lines;
    ntab_lines.lines = NULL;
    ntab_lines.max_elements = 0;
    ntab_lines.index = 0;
    node_t *words = NULL;
    int word_counter = 0;

    char *exp_filename = NULL;
    struct Ntab ntab_exp_lines;
    ntab_exp_lines.lines = NULL;
    ntab_lines.max_elements = 0;
    ntab_lines.index = 0;
    node_t *exp_words = NULL;
    int exp_word_counter = 0;

    command_line_input(argc, argv, &filename, &exp_filename);

    read_file_in_array(filename, &ntab_lines);
    store_words(&ntab_lines, &words, &word_counter);

    read_file_in_array(exp_filename, &ntab_exp_lines);
    store_words(&ntab_exp_lines, &exp_words, &exp_word_counter);
    remove_exceptions(&words, &exp_words, &word_counter);

    print_output(&words, &ntab_lines, word_counter);

#ifdef DEBUG
    _demo();
#endif

    exit(0);
}

void command_line_input(int argc, char *argv[], char **input_file, char **exp_file){
    if (argc == 2){
        *input_file = argv[1];
        *exp_file = NULL;
    }else if(argc == 4){
        if(strcmp(argv[2],"-e") == 0){
            *exp_file = argv[3];
            *input_file = argv[1];
        }else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0){
            *exp_file = argv[2];
            *input_file = argv[3];
        }
    }else if(argc == 1 || argc == 3){
        printf("Need more arguments");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void read_file_in_array(char *filename, struct Ntab *ntab){
    FILE *fptr;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1){
        add_line(line, ntab);
    }

    fclose(fptr);
}

int add_line(char *line, struct Ntab *ntab){
    struct Lines_and_Words *lp;

    if (ntab->lines == NULL){
        ntab->lines = (Lines_and_Words *)malloc(NINIT * sizeof(Lines_and_Words));
        if (ntab->lines == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        ntab->max_elements = NINIT;
        ntab->index = 0;
    }else if(ntab->index >= ntab->max_elements){
        lp = (Lines_and_Words *) realloc(ntab->lines, (NGROW * ntab->max_elements) * sizeof(Lines_and_Words));
        if (lp == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        ntab->max_elements *= NGROW;
        ntab->lines = lp;
    }
    strncpy(ntab->lines[ntab->index].array_lines, line, MAX_LINE_LEN);
    return ntab->index++;
}

void store_words(struct Ntab *ntab, node_t **words, int *word_counter){
    int buff_line_num = 0;
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    const char delim[] = " \n";
    char *token;
    char token_temp[MAX_WORD_LEN];

    for (int i = 0; i<ntab->index; i++){
        strncpy(buffer, ntab->lines[i].array_lines, MAX_LINE_LEN);
        token = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while (token != NULL){

            strncpy(token_temp, token, MAX_WORD_LEN);
            for (int i = 0; i<strlen(token_temp); i++){
                token_temp[i] = tolower(token_temp[i]);
            }

            node_t *new_p = new_node(token_temp);
            *words = add_end(*words, new_p);
            *word_counter = *word_counter + 1;

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        buff_line_num++;
    }
}

void remove_exceptions(node_t **words, node_t **exp_words, int *word_counter){
    node_t *curr;
    node_t *curr2;

    for (curr = *words; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
        for(curr2 = *exp_words; curr2 != NULL; curr2 = curr2->next){
            if (strcmp(curr->text, curr2->text) == 0){
                printf("%s: %s\n", curr->text, curr2->text);
                *words = remove_word(*words, curr->text);
                *word_counter = *word_counter - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

node_t *remove_word(node_t *words, char *text){
    node_t *curr, *prev;
    prev = NULL;

    for (curr = words; curr != NULL; curr = curr-> next){
        if (strcmp(text, curr->text) == 0) {
            if (prev == NULL){
                words = curr->next;
            }else{
                prev->next = curr->next;
            }
            free(curr);
            return words;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "delitem: %s not in list", text);
    exit(1);
}


void sort(node_t **words, int word_counter){
    char buffer[word_counter][MAX_WORD_LEN];
    node_t *curr = *words;
    int index = 0;

    while (curr != NULL && index <= word_counter){
        strncpy(buffer[index], curr->text, MAX_WORD_LEN);
        curr = curr->next;
        index = index + 1;
    }

    qsort(buffer, word_counter, MAX_WORD_LEN*sizeof(char), compare);
    *words = NULL;

    for (int i=0; i<word_counter; i++){
        node_t *new_p = new_node(buffer[i]);
        *words = add_end(*words, new_p);
    }
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char *sa = (char *)a;
    char *sb = (char *)b;

    return(strcmp(sa, sb));
}

//https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-a-sorted-linked-list/
void remove_duplicates(node_t **words, int *word_counter){
    node_t *curr = *words;
    node_t *temp;

    if (curr == NULL){
        return;
    }

    while (curr->next != NULL){
        if (strcmp(curr->text, curr->next->text) == 0){
            temp = curr->next->next;
            free(curr->next);
            curr->next = temp;
        }else{
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}


void print_output(node_t **words, struct Ntab *ntab_lines, int word_counter){
    int occur_count = 0;
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char word_temp[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    node_t *curr;

    int longest = (-1) * (longest_word(words) + 2);

    for (curr = *words; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
        for (int j = 0; j<ntab_lines->index; j++){
            strncpy(buffer, ntab_lines->lines[j].array_lines, MAX_LINE_LEN);

            occur_count = count_words_in_line(curr->text, buffer);

            if (occur_count == 1){
                strncpy(word_temp, curr->text, MAX_WORD_LEN);
                for (int m = 0; m<strlen(word_temp); m++){
                    word_temp[m] = toupper(word_temp[m]);
                }
                strncpy(&buffer[strlen(buffer)-1], "\0", 1);
                printf("%*s%s (%d)\n", longest, word_temp, buffer, j+1);
            }else if(occur_count > 1){
                strncpy(word_temp, curr->text, MAX_WORD_LEN);
                for (int m = 0; m<strlen(word_temp); m++){
                    word_temp[m] = toupper(word_temp[m]);
                }
                strncpy(&buffer[strlen(buffer)-1], "\0", 1);
                printf("%*s%s (%d*)\n", longest, word_temp, buffer, j+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int longest_word(node_t **words){
    int longest_length = 0;

    node_t *curr;
    for (curr = *words; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
        if (strlen(curr->text) > longest_length){
            longest_length = strlen(curr->text);
        }
    }
    return(longest_length);
}

//https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c-program-for-lowercase-to-uppercase-and-vice-versa
int count_words_in_line(char word[MAX_WORD_LEN], char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN]){
    int word_count = 0;
    int occur_count = 0;
    char temp[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    node_t *words_in_a_line = NULL;
    char *token;
    node_t *curr;

    const char delim[] = " \n";

    strncpy(temp, buffer, MAX_LINE_LEN);
    for (int i = 0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if (temp[i] >= 'A' && temp[i] <= 'Z'){
            temp[i] = temp[i] + 32;
        }
    }

    token = strtok(temp, delim);
    while (token != NULL){
        node_t *new_p = new_node(token);
        words_in_a_line = add_end(words_in_a_line, new_p);

        word_count++;

        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    for (curr = words_in_a_line; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
        if (strcmp(curr->text, word) == 0){
            occur_count++;
        }
    }

    return(occur_count);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have used your own header files and we are unaware of their contents. It would be better if you update their contents or link to them here.

Comment: That's both too much and too little code. Your question is about `remove_exceptions`, yet you provide the full program. Cut the code down to the necessary parts. On the other hand, you don't provide the list implementation itself or example input. Now *that* would have been helpful. Please write a minimal, reprodicuble example.

Comment: At first glance, your code is quite inconsistent. Sometimes you use the `head = do_stuff(head)` approach, other times, you use `process(&head)`. You cite where you got the implementations from in comments. Please take your time to actually unserstand what the code does, then unify it to whatever style you like best. As is, the code looks like scraps and patches collected from the internet verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

When you find a word in the exception list, you delete it with:

```
*words = remove_word(*words, curr->text);
```

Okay, that node was removed. Let's look at the rest of the list.

```
curr = curr->next;
```

Uh-oh! We have just deleted `curr` with `free`, so it is no longer valid to access that memory. That is *undefined behaviour*, which is very likely to account for your segfault.

Let's first modify the signature of your function. You use a wild mix of different styles for linked lists. I prefer passing a pointer to the head pointer, which removes the redundancy in the call and which makes it clear that the head pointer might e modified. (You do that already in your function.)

On the other hand, you don't need to pass in a pointer to the head pointer of the list of exception words. That list is read-only and will not be modified. Lastly, the function is `void`. We can use the return value to report the number of removed items, which the caller can ignore.

So:

```
int list_filter(node_t **head, node_t *filter)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (*head) {
        if (list_find(filter, (*head)->text)) {
            node_t *node = *head;

            *head = node->next;
            count++;

            free(node);
        } else {        
            head = &(*head)->next;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Here `*head` is always valid, because it points either to the head node in the caller function or to the `next` field of the preceding node; `*head` points to a valid node or is `NULL`.

The function `list_find` is a straightforward helper function that finds a node:

```
node_t *list_find(node_t *node, const char *text)
{
    while (node) {
        if (strcmp(node->text, text) == 0) break;
        node = node->next;
    }

    return node;
}
```